# Iterate over a list with floats, and use them in math equations

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate over a list with floats and calculate with the items in the lists, but I always get this:

> list indices must be integers or slices, not float

as you can see below, there are lists named `t`, and `sdt` which have the same length and are both floats:

```
for i in t:
    if t[i] == t[0] or t[1] or t[2] or t[3]:
        for i in t[0:4]:
            rp1x = r+h
            rp1y = sdt[i] - .5*(l-w)
            print(rp1x, rp1y)
```

Comment: `for i in t:` doesn't make `i` the indexes. `i` will hold the values in `t`. Also, this doesn't work the way you think: `t[i] == t[0] or t[1] or t[2] or t[3]` you need to make separate conditions.

Comment: `for i in t[0:4]:` shadows the first `for i in t`

Comment: replace `if t[i] == t[0] or t[1] or t[2] or t[3]:` with `if t[i] in (t[0], t[1], t[2], t[3]):`

Comment: Try `for i in range(len(t))`:  for the first loop and `for j in range(4):' for the second. I assume it is a mistake that you used the same loop index in both loops. Moreover, in the if condition, you can only use `or' with Boolean values. So try `t[i] == t[0] or t[i] == t[1] or ... `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to use the items from your list as indices, you should use:

```
my_items = t[0:4]
for item in t:
    if item in my_items:
        for i in my_items:
            rp1x = r+h
            rp1y = sdt[i] - .5*(l-w)
            print(rp1x, rp1y)
```

Comment: `t[i] == t[0] or t[1] or t[2] or t[3]` is completely wrong